# Reading particular line in a file for a particular word in PHP

Tags: php

I am new to php, I need to read a text file's 5th line and see if it contains a particular string
what would be the most efficient way to do it ?
I understand I can ready all lines using this method, should I put a counter here and break the loop if it is 5 ? or is there a better way to it ..

```
 $file = fopen($fileName,'r');
    while(!feof($file)) 
    { 
        $name = fgets($file);            
    }

    fclose($file);
```

EDIT

I have updated my code to this, but strpos always fails to find the string even if it is present..
I have verified the 5th line looks like this
    PACKAGE_NAME: com.boom.appfree

```
//read entire file into an array 
$lines = file($target_path);

//check line 5 if it contains free
$pos = strpos($line[4], 'free');

if ($pos === false) 
{
  $subject = "Paid Log uploaded";
} else 
{
   $subject = "Log uploaded";
}
```

Any advise please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$lines =`[`file`](http://php.net/file)`("filename.txt");`

Then you can get the fifth line: `$lines[4]` and search it for the word you are looking for with `strpos`.

Comment: thanks, it partly worked but strpos always fails to find the string, I have updated my question with my new code

Comment: thanks it worked out in the strops I used $line[4] the actual variable was $lines.. crap :( I am a Java/C++ programmer where vars are declared before use, php is quite funny :)

Answer (score 0):

If the lines of your file are of equal size, you can use fseek: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php to jump to the 5th line.

Otherwise adding a counter and breaking the while loop will work just fine.